# How to check for a PARTICULAR SMS received through broadcast receivers in Android

Tags: android

I have developed an application which listens for all incoming SMS (using Broadcast Receiver) but I want to make my application activate an activity when it listen a Particular SMS (Ex. "LOCATIONRECQEST" sended from mobile no. say - 98765...).
So, basically I want to know is how to check the content of SMS (and do some task accordingly).
Also I want to get the number from which the SMS had been sent.
Any Help is awaited.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read SMS content, you can use a **ContentResolver** :

```
// Uri of the SMS inbox
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// Query
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

if (null != c && c.moveToFirst()) {

    // For all SMS
    // do { 

    String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")); // Date (Timestamp)
    String adress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")); // Phone number
    String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")); // Message

    // For all SMS  
    // }while(c.moveToNext());

}
```

To find a String in your SMS content :

```
String body = "this is the text of the sms - code 25D45 - ...";
String stringToFind = "25D45";

// return the position of the "stringToFind"
if(body.indexOf(stringToFind) != -1) {

    // your action here

}
```

Comment: I am getting the message received by the following code, but i want to comapare the received message with some string. How can i do?

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }